# Rails bundle install fails because "byebug requires ruby version >= 2.0.0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

I tried on ruby versions `2.0.0, 2.1.5` and `2.2.1`. 
Also `gem install byebug -v '5.0.0'` installs byebug succesfully. `byebug -v` returns: Running byebug 5.0.0, but `bundle install` still fails and gives me error "byebug requires ruby version >= 2.0.0".

Comment: It might happen that bundle is using an older version of Ruby - can you check what does `bundle exec ruby -v` return?

Comment: Sometimes you have an old version of Ruby declared in your app or you have a ruby version downloaded but not set as default (if you use rbenv call 'rbenv global 2.2.3')

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well, what helped me was to run ruby -v and see that I have the "correct"-version and then I ran the bundle update and restart the server, close all my tabs and start over again.

Answer (score 0):

so,  we can see through few possibilities,  one is,  there could be any predefined ruby declared inside your ruby app..check for it..  and change it. two... if you are using version manager like rvm then,  check that you are using the current version more than 2.0.